# PHP: How can create an array from radio button and save to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this code HTML :-

```
<label>Show Full Name</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="fullname" >
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fullname"  >

<label>Show Job</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="job"  >
<input type="radio" value="0" name="job" >

<label>Show Fav</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="fav" >
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fav" >
```

Now I need to save this value to database an array like this format :-

```
$a = array( 
            'fullname' => '1',
            'job' => '0',
            'fav'  => '1'
          );
```

And when save it, How can i read it and Check it here :-

```
<label>Show Full Name</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="fullname" <? if ($fullname == '1') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fullname" <? if ($fullname == '0') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >

<label>Show Job</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="job" <? if ($job== '1') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
<input type="radio" value="0" name="job" <? if ($job== '0') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >

<label>Show Fav</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="fav" <? if ($fav== '1') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fav" <? if ($fav== '0') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
```

==================

**Update:-**

Now we cansave array , but when retrive data i canot get it

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT req from formsreq where id = 1";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $data= json_decode($result['req']);
        $fullname = $data['fullname'];
        $bridthdate = $data['bridthdate'];
        $wherebridth = $data['wherebridth'];
        $nationalty = $data['nationalty'];
        $whereplace = $data['whereplace'];
        $job = $data['job'];
        $degree = $data['degree'];
        $special = $data['special'];
        $enjaz = $data['enjaz'];
        $morashah = $data['morashah'];
        $jeha = $data['jeha'];
        $maswagha = $data['maswagha'];
        $cv = $data['cv'];
        $work = $data['work'];

    }
?>

<label>Show Full Name</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="fullname" <? if ($fullname == '1') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
<input type="radio" value="0" name="fullname" <? if ($fullname == '0') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
```

Where is error !

Comment: I don't really understand what kind of help do you need? You don't know how to retrieve the values from the database?

Comment: What is the purpose to save in array format ?

Comment: @Codrutz i need how can i save like array format i posted in my post and how can read it ??

Comment: `json_encode`/`json_decode`, `seriaize`/`unserialize` and others. Read the manual.

Comment: @TBIless i need to save only, Are there another way to save ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your html code will be in a form. After the submit, the action of the form (let's call it test.php), will handle the SQL operations.

test.php :

```
<?php

$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$job = $_POST['job'];
$fav = $_POST['fav'];

$a = array( 
            'fullname' => $fullname,
            'job' => $job,
            'fav'  => $fav
);
$json = json_encode($a);
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tbl (data) VALUES ('".$json."') ");
?>
```

As you can see, the data has been `json` encoded and inserted into the table.

When you want to retrieve and analyze the data, you can do this:

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT data from tbl where id = ".$id;
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $data= json_decode($result['data']);
        $fullname = $data['fullname'];
        $job = $data['job'];
        $fav = $data['fav'];
    }
?>    

    <label>Show Full Name</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="fullname" <? if ($fullname == '1') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
    <input type="radio" value="0" name="fullname" <? if ($fullname == '0') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >

    <label>Show Job</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="job" <? if ($job== '1') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
    <input type="radio" value="0" name="job" <? if ($job== '0') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >

    <label>Show Fav</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="fav" <? if ($fav== '1') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
    <input type="radio" value="0" name="fav" <? if ($fav== '0') {?> checked="checked" <? } ?> >
```

Comment: thank, but its save good, but when i retrieve data. i canot get it 
place see my update post

Comment: I cannot help you without knowing what kind of error are you getting. Please update.